# About retrieving a value from a 2-dimensional dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
const int Rbn_Row = 24, Rbn_Col = 32;

Map = (char**)malloc(Rbn_Col * sizeof(char*));
for (int Cnt = 0; Cnt < Rbn_Col; Cnt++)
    *(Map + Cnt) = (char*)malloc(Rbn_Row * sizeof(char)); /* <--- line 5       */

Map[2][3]=99;
printf("%d\n", Map[2][3]);                                /* <--- works        */
printf("%d\n", *(Map+2*Rbn_Col+3));                       /* <--- doesn't work */
```

- Should I add `(char*)` in the fifth line and why?
- Why doesn't the second `printf` work whereas the first one does as expected?

Comment: Because your memory isn't contiguous, and you only dereferenced once.

Comment: Don't typecast malloc. It is not necessary nor safe. And yeah, you could put `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth So it should be `*(*(Map+2)+3)`, right?

Comment: There's no multidimensional array in this question, I only see pointers.

Comment: Yes, `*(*(Map+2)+3)` (conventionally written `Map[2][3]`) is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first malloc you create a contiguous array of 32 pointer. In the for you assigned a new values to these pointers, now they're have reference to another memory. So if you take Map+3 you do not reference to first row-third column, but it references to third line.

If you need a contiguous memory, you can also create a simple 1-dimensional array:

```
Map = malloc(Rbn_Row * Rbn_Col * sizeof(char));
```

Now you can access contiguously:

```
*(Map + row * Rbn_Col + column)
```

Answer (score 0):

You make the wrong assumption that the 32 calls to `malloc` return contiguous memory. What makes you think so?
If you want contiguous memory, you must allocate your array with a single `malloc`,

```
char *Map;
Map = malloc (Rbn_Row * Rbn_Col * sizeof *Map);
```